# How to show amount in round figure for Odoo 10

Tags: floating-point, rounding, odoo, odoo-10

I have a float field and i can calculate amount within this field. I want that amount should show in round figure. For eg. when price is 64.80 then it updated to 65 and if price 64.40 then it updated to 64.
So, what solution i could use?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you need the decimal or math module:

```py
import decimal
a = decimal.Decimal("8.833333333339")
print(round(a,2))
8.83

import math
v = 2.357
print(math.ceil(v*100)/100)  # -> 2.36
print(math.floor(v*100)/100)  # -> 2.35
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved by just using 'round'. For eg. round(amount).
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this code :**

```
import decimal
a = 64.80
b = 64.20
print(round(a,0)) //output 65.0
print(round(b,0)) //output 64.0
```